# Show DatePart once and then Only time in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I have following DataSet which  is  grouped by dates .

```
[ '2017-01-12',
[ { completedAt: Fri Jan 13 2017 06:32:04 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
   Min: 658,
    name: 'tariq',
     startedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 19:33:40 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
     },
  { completedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 19:30:28 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Min: 1,
  name: 'tariq',
  startedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 19:29:06 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
   },
{ completedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 18:12:58 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Min: 0,
  name: 'tariq',
  startedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 18:12:55 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  },
{ completedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 18:11:14 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Min: 688,
  name: 'tariq',
  startedAt: Thu Jan 12 2017 06:42:46 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
   } ] ]
```

I want  to  show only date once in my  views and  then  the  only time part coming in that  date . here is  what i want like in my  views

Comment: You can try `new Date(obj.startedAt).toLocaleTimeString()`. Note, its not supported in all browsers, so please check compatibility before using it